# Какой оптимальный размер методов?

Tags: любой-язык

Иногда копаюсь в исходниках `.NET` ради интереса и очень часто встречаю длиннющие методы, [например](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,76ef6c04de9d0ed8,references).

Во всяких книгах пишут, что метод не должен превышать размер одного экрана прокрутки.

Однако тот метод, который я привел в примере, имеет монструозный размер... Наверное, где-то 5 экранов. Даже если убрать комментарии, то ситуация сильно лучше не становится. Хотя с виду это все можно было бы поделить на небольшие методы с говорящими названиями.

Разве это правильно? Или Microsoft - это плохой пример для подражания?

Comment: Там же используется условная компиляция. Из-за нее сложно поделить на методы. К тому же, это mscorlib - _ядро_ дотнета, самая часто испоьзуемая библиотека, она должна быть максимально эффективной и быстрой. В данном случае можно поступиться читаемостью методов, обеспечив производительность. Об этом говорит и использование unsafe.

Comment: Текущие ответы не полны. Почему-то никто не захотел в ответе указать то, о чём пишет @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 7):

То что вы описали, скорее совет, нежели правило. Если логика метода такова, что ему нужно быть на 5 экранов, то почему нет. Другой вопрос, если можно логику разделить на отдельные методы, то для лучшей читаемости это стоит сделать. Но в то же время не стоит пораждать класс методами, которые будут вызываться лишь 1 раз и нигде больше не использоваться.

***Во всем главное соблюдать баланс и придерживаться здравого смысла!***

Comment: Ну не знаю. Мне кажется, что любой код можно разбить на маленькие методы, если конечно там не 5 экранов объявлений переменных... То что функция вызывается 1 раз фиксится созданием какого-нибудь внутренного статического класса хелпера или внутренних функций(C# 7.0)

Comment: я не программирую на C#, но подозреваю, что как и в любом языке статический класс-хелпер - это как раз тот кейс, когда есть "неудобный код", который нужен везде и в разных местах, но нельзя отнести к одному какому-либо случаю

Answer (score 2):

Если не забывать о том, что программирование это вид искусства, то правильного ответа на данный вопрос быть не может. У разных людей разные чувства стиля, вкуса, корректности, полноты, желания, темперамента и так далее. Есть только несколько рекомендаций, но люди понимают их по-своему.
Пишите понятно, красиво, атомарно (с точки зрения цели функции, или метода). Если ваша атомарность это пять экранов, что же и в программировании есть место для Церетели ))

Answer (score 2):

> Во всяких книгах пишут...

В этих книгах пишут, в основном, про разработку корпоративного ПО.

У корпоративного и системного ПО (например, .NET core) разные требования, связанные со спецификой разработки и использования.